# Why is $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{x+1}$ for $x > 0$?

Tags: intuition, congruences, proof-explanation

One day my mind wandered off and came upon the following.

$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{x+1}~\forall x>0, x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My markdown might be a little bit broken :)

I tested this out in Python for the first $1000$ values of $x$ and it seems to work out. In case my congruence is hard to understand, I just mean that the remainder of $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is $1.$

Can anyone provide any intuition for this property?

Comment: $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod c$ means that $c$ is a factor of $a-b$. Is $x+1$ a factor of $x^2-1$?

Comment: Thanks lulu! That is very intuitive! I would give you the the best answer but I don't know if you can with comments :)

Comment: haha I can't tell if that was supposed to be sarcasm (since it gave no intuitive justification and the question is tagged `intuition`) or otherwise (since it gave a witness to the congruence and the question is tagged `proof-explanation`)

Comment: Nope it's not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of mod $x+1$ as meaning $x = -1$, then $x^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Just thought it might help to use a different symbol than =, so rephrasing this solution :: Let $x \sim y$ mean x and y are equivalent module $x+1$, then we have $x+1 \sim 0$ and so $x \sim −1$ then $x^2 \sim (−1)^2 \sim 1$. Notice that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and so we have that **Intuitively** the lemma says: if we identify $x$ with $−1$ then $x^2$ can be identified with $1$. More generally, $mod \ m$ means that we are in a context where we want to *identify* $m$ with 0.

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv b \mod n$

If $n$ divides $a-b$ (hence $b-a$). Since $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, of course $x+1$ divides $x^2-1$.